# Positioning div above image dynamically via mouseover

Tags: javascript

I want to display div above image so that div's top is aligned with cursor.
As cursor is moved, the div should be moved as well (right now just vertically).
In IE (**pure javascript please**).

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
       #ToolTip{position:absolute; width: 200px;background-color:Lime; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index:400;visibility:hidden;}
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function On() {

            MoveToolTip("ToolTip", "event.y", "event.x");
            document.getElementById('ToolTip').style.visibility = 'visible';

        }
        function Off() {

            MoveToolTip("ToolTip", 0, 0);
            document.getElementById('ToolTip').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

        function MoveToolTip(layerName, top, left) {
               document.getElementById(layerName).style.top = (eval(top));
             //document.getElementById(layerName).style.left = (eval(left) - 360);

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="ToolTip" >This is a test </div>   
        <a href="www.www.com"><img alt="mg" border="0" src="http://www.google.com/logos/holiday09_4.gif"  onmouseout="Off();" onmouseover="On();" /></a>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible fix for your problem:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    #ToolTip {
        position:absolute; 
        width: 200px;
        background-color:Lime;
        z-index:400;
        visibility:hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="ToolTip">This is a test</div>
        <a href="www.www.com">
            <img alt="mg" id="base-img" border="0" src="http://www.google.com/logos/holiday09_4.gif" />
        </a>
    </div>
    </form>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showToolTip(e) {
        e = e || window.event; // Older versions of IE handle events funny
        // Added code that compensates for the window's scroll position.
        var top = e.clientY + (window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop) + 5;
        moveToolTip("ToolTip", top, e.clientX);
        document.getElementById('ToolTip').style.visibility = 'visible';

        // We need to cancel the center to ensure that the onmousemove event 
        // on the body element doesn't get triggered
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) { e.stopPropagation(); }
        return false;
    }
    function hideToolTip() {
        moveToolTip("ToolTip", 0, 0);
        document.getElementById('ToolTip').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        return false;
    }

    function moveToolTip(layerName, top, left) {
        document.getElementById(layerName).style.top = (top + "px");
    }

    document.onmousemove = hideToolTip;
    document.getElementById("ToolTip").onmousemove = showToolTip;
    document.getElementById("base-img").onmousemove = showToolTip;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Things I changed:

- Gave functions more readable names:

  - Renamed `On` to `showToolTip`
  - Renamed `Off` to `hideToolTip`
- The `event` variable is now passed to the `showToolTip` function.  This is needed to get the cursor's x, y position
- Added code that compensated for the window's scroll position
- Added `return false` to `showToolTip` and `hideToolTip`
- Replaced `onmouseout` and `onmouseover` with the more widely supported `onmousemove` event
- Got rid of the flicker by adding the following:

  - Added `onmousemove` event to document, which calls `hideToolTip`
  - Added `onmousemove` event to the tool tip div, which calls `showToolTip`
- Added `+ "px"` statement to the `.style.top` assignment.  Some browsers get confuse if you assign an integer to a style.
- Moved script declarations to the bottom of the page.
- Moved event assignments to javascript and removed `onmousemove` attributes from the markup
- Added the `cursor: pointer` style to the tool tip.  This removes cursor flicker.
- Changed code format

I've also posted a working example: http://www.the-xavi.com/static/so-hover-div.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't move div as I move the cursor above image.

Comment: and also document.body.scrollTop doesn't work, at least not in IE8

Comment: I've added to your solution onmousemove event (similar to Can Berk Güder suggestion), and changed document.body.scrollTop to document.documentElement.scrollTop; Now the problem is flicker

Comment: hmm, I saw none of those problems when I did testing on my end.  Give me a second I'll re-write the code to make it much more robust.

Comment: I posted a more robust version of the code, let me know if you're still having problems with it.

Comment: Well...this is a PERFECT answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve something like this using jQuery and the plugin [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Edit: The problem with the javascript code is that you are not referencing actual screen positions in your move function, just text. You'll have to get the actual position of the cursor in the on/off function as pass it as a number to the move function.

Comment: I don't want that, pure JS please.

Comment: +1, if there is a stable plugin for jQuery that can handle this, it's proven to save a lot of pain.

Comment: Updated link to qTipe (which is widely used and is pretty good) and tried to answer the question sans jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You might want to optimize this to avoid flickering.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#ToolTip {
 position: absolute;
 visibility: hidden;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function Move(e) {
 MoveToolTip("ToolTip", e.x, e.y);
}

function On(e) {
 MoveToolTip("ToolTip", e.x, e.y);
 document.getElementById("theImage").onmousemove = Move;
 document.getElementById("ToolTip").style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function Off(e) {
 document.getElementById("theImage").onmousemove = null;
 document.getElementById("ToolTip").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function MoveToolTip(layerName, x, y) {
 document.getElementById(layerName).style.left = x + 'px';
 document.getElementById(layerName).style.top = y + 'px';
}

function init() {
 document.getElementById("theImage").onmouseover = On;
 document.getElementById("theImage").onmouseout = Off;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div>
        <div id="ToolTip">This is a test</div>
        <a href="www.www.com"><img id="theImage" alt="mg" border="0" src="http://www.google.com/logos/holiday09_4.gif" /></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by optimizing?

Comment: I get an error (inside function On): Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'x' is null or not an object

Comment: first step would be to reduce the number of document.getElementById calls. also, MoveToolTip can be made inline.

I can't test this on IE, so I don't know what causes that error, but this is pure JS, it should work on all browsers?

Comment: There is some problem with event passing, function On(e) e is empty.